# Why can't I print values of linked list members?

Tags: c, linked-list

In the C code below I create a linked list and a function that prints the `int` values of the members. I created some sample members in the `main` however nothing gets printed and I can't figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node * ptr;
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  ptr next;
} item;

void printList(ptr p);

int main() {
  item h1 = {12, NULL};
  item h2 = {13, h1.next};
  item h3 = {14, h2.next};
  printList(h3.next);
}

void printList(ptr p) {
  while(p) {
    printf("%d -> \n", ptr -> data);
    ptr = ptr -> next;
  }
}
```

Comment: You inited all `next` members to `NULL`.....so.....

Comment: but why? I only initiated `h1` to `NULL` while `h3` points to non-NULL `h2`

Comment: `item h3 = {14, h2.next};` ---> `item h3 = {14, &h2};`

Comment: the suggestion above doesn't work either

Comment: `h1.next` is `NULL` because you set it that way in the `h1` initialization. So is `h2.next`. If you don't believe it, try `printf("%p\n", h2.next");` etc.

Comment: You didn't post a [mcve]. You example doesn't compile even.

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to typedef pointers.

Comment: I have to use `typedef` in my class

Comment: This is the way they recommended to do this in our class. With your `struct` I'd have to add `struct` to the signature of every function that uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initialization is wrong.

```
 item h2 = {13, h1.next};
```

Initialize `h2` `next` member pointer to content of `next` member of `h1`, that is `NULL`, and the same for `h3`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} item;

void printList(item *p);

int main(void) {
  item h1 = {12, NULL};
  item h2 = {13, &h1};
  item h3 = {14, &h2};
  printList(&h3);
}

void printList(item *p) {
  while(p) {
    printf("%d -> \n", p->data);
    p = p->next;
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
14 -> 
13 -> 
12 ->
```

**Side note:**
Avoid to hide pointers with `typedef`, make the code difficult to understand if the code grows a lot with many layers.

Answer (score 1):

changing this code

```
item h1 = {12, NULL};
item h2 = {13, h1.next};
item h3 = {14, h2.next};
```

to the following will solve your problem

```
item h1 = {12, NULL};
item h2 = {13, &h1};
item h3 = {14, &h2};
```

Answer (score 1):

`h3.next` is initialized to `h2.next`, which is initialized to `h1.next`, which is initialized to `NULL`, so all of them are `NULL`.
Obviously, there is nothing to print at `NULL`.

You might need to build your initialization chain the other way round.